# jQuery collision plugin | How to actually check if something collided

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, collision-detection, pong, jquery-collision

I'm using [jQuery Collision](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/) in a simple (or so I thought) game of Pong. There's no AI or online interaction, just two paddles and the ball that one or two players in real life can control.

When trying to animate the ball and check if it actually collided with anything, I'm coming up short. I've read the documentation on SourceForge (see above link), but I'm still a bit lost on how to actually check if the collider actually hit anything. The documentation could use a few examples, in my opinion.

JavaScript code I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ball = $("#ball");
    var topPaddle = $("topPaddle");
    var bottomPaddle = $("bottomPaddle");
    var topPaddleHits = $("#ball").collision("#topPaddle", { mode: "collision", obstacleData: "topOData" });
    var bottomPaddleHits = $("#ball").collision("#bottomPaddle", { mode: "collision", obstacleData: "bottomOData" });
    var anim = setInterval(function()
    {
        ball.css({ "left": "+=5", "top": "+=5" });
        if (bottomPaddleHits.data("bottomOData") == bottomPaddle)
        {
            anim = clearInterval(anim);
            alert("Bottom paddle hit!");
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

I've also tried `if (bottomPaddleHits == 1)` but that was no good, either.

---

CSS for the top/bottom paddles and the ball, if it matters:

```
#ball
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
}   
#topPaddle
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 10px;
    background: lime;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
#bottomPaddle
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 10px;
    background: lime;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

I'm just not sure how to go about checking if something was actually hit or not.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using it doesn't work with jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.2, both from Google's CDN.

Comment: Pretty sure anything over 1.8 won't work because the API has changed.

Answer (score 1):

That collision plugin seems to have pretty crappy documentation I would think it would be much easier using something like jQuery UI which has way better documentation and support. Here is something quick I put together that detects collision.

```
<div class="drop">
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
</div>

$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

$('.drag').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
});

$('.drag').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        //ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
        alert('touched');
    }
});
```

and where the alert is placed you can use the ui argument to get the position and offset of where the collision occurred.

http://jsfiddle.net/kAXdE/

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should mentioned that the top paddle is controlled by the keys A and D, and the bottom one is controlled by the mouse. Is it possible to bind such events using jQuery UI? It's not just drag and drop like your example.